# Upload .SQL Files to Wiki

Tags: php, sql, wiki, mediawiki

Changes to my team's database are recorded in our internal wiki. Currently, in addition to a brief description, the .sql scripts are added as text. This is becoming bulky and making the page difficult to read. I'm trying to configure mediawiki to allow .sql files to be uploaded, so they can just be linked to from the changes list.

I added 'sql' to the array of accept file extensions in `LocalSettings.php`. Attempting to upload a SQL script I get the following warning:

> The file is corrupt or has an incorrect extension. Please check the file and upload again.

Uploading is already configured and works for the file types previously chosen. I've read several manual pages from MediaWiki, but they have not been able to help me resolve the problem. I found that some files may need to be white-listed, but .SQL was not in the [$wgFileBlacklist](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgFileBlacklist) or the [$wgMimeTypeBlacklist](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgMimeTypeBlacklist). The [configuring uploads article](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads) in the manual states this error could be due to MIME type detection not working correctly. Googling has also yielded no relevant answers.

**How can I configure my mediawiki to allow .SQL file uploads?**

What I'm working with:

- MediaWiki 1.15.5-7
- PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 (apache2handler)
- MySQL 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2

Answer (score 2):

First of all, see [this page](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Uploading_files#The_file_is_corrupt_or_has_an_incorrect_extension._Please_check_the_file_and_upload_again.) about your specific error message. The problem seems to be triggered by [MIME type detection](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MIME_type_detection). Try setting [`$wgVerifyMimeType`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgVerifyMimeType) to `false` and see if it resolves the problem. If it does, you need to reconfigure [`$wgMimeTypeBlacklist`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgMimeTypeBlacklist).

If [`$wgStrictFileExtensions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgStrictFileExtensions) is set to `true` (and this is the default), only files with extensions listed in [`$wgFileExtensions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgFileExtensions) will be allowed (whitelisting).

Just add in `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgFileExtensions[] = 'sql';
```

If that doesn't work, set [`$wgStrictFileExtensions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgStrictFileExtensions) to `false` *temporarily* (this can expose you to security risks).

To disable **all** security checks on files, set [`$wgCheckFileExtensions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCheckFileExtensions) to false.